# Textarea with key # and show label box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
```

I want when I type in textarea using #. Example #happy, #2012, etc. After submit, it will show with div label box. Using this css :

```
.div_box
{
padding: 5px;
background: #c0c0c0;
}
```

Is it possible to make it happen?
Let me know, if you have an idea ?
Thanks for helps.

Comment: having dificulty understanding your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: When you say submit, what do you mean? Submit traditionally loads a new page, unless you intercept the call and do the POST manually. Do you want to reload the page or manually POST?

Comment: The point is if I submit textarea using #blabal... The display of textarea result label must have a div_box class

Comment: @tjameson dont think about the submit, now I talked about display after submit.

Comment: So, do you just want to add the `.div_box` class to #text when there's a hash tag in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it whenever the document is loaded.

Using Javascript only:

```
    window.onload = function(){
        if(document.getElementById('text').innerHTML.indexOf('#') != -1){
            document.getElementById('text').setAttribute('class','div_box');
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('text').setAttribute('class','');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way we can change the class of particular text in text area. We can only change the class of an element.
For this we can use already made "Rich Text Editor" and manually do that.

If there is another method. please let me know